# Smarty array assign to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I am new at Smarty.
I have a smarty array `$order_info`

How can I assign the value `{$order_info.email}` to a PHP string?

I hope someone can help me!

Solution:

```
{/php}
     {$order_info.email}
{php}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Generally smarty is for displaying stuff not for adding values to things to pass back to PHP.

Comment: Yes i know. I want to convert the smarty to php string for a hack.

Comment: @RightHandedMonkey I think he wants to assign email value to some other variable in loop.

Comment: @Bas how on earth is that supposed to work? Could you give some more details please?

Comment: what has been answered (and accepted) below makes no sense for your own edit of the question. Also the question itself is not clear what you're asking. I don't see a reason to keep this on a Q&A site and therefore voted to close it. Will also vote to delete it. Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl you should be able to run the following code:

#### Smarty template

```
{assign var="email" value=$order_info.email}
```

#### PHP Script

```
// First fetch the template!
$whole_page = $smarty->fetch('index.tpl');

// Then get the variable:
$email = $smarty->getTemplateVars('email');
echo "The email in a PHP variable: " . $email;
```

Comment: This doesnt work. If i do {$order_info.email} this then the emailadres diplayed. Do i need to give a key?!

Comment: i am getting this notice Notice: Undefined variable: smarty in. Its a opensource software. how can i find the wright variable